# Jquery hide/show delay fix

Tags: jquery, html

Hey i have 2 blocks in the same place where people can put in a number. If there is no number it hides. But i want to give them the time to change it to another number. So i delay the hiding with ms. But then they see an animation of the hiding/showing. Is there a way to fix?

```
$('#FenceMeters').on('input', function() {
  if($('#FenceMeters').val() != "" && Number($('#FenceMeters').val()) >=5){
     $('#testje').show();
     $('#SummaryHTML').hide();
  } else{
    $('#testje').hide(1000);
    $('#SummaryHTML').show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `.hide()` will immediately make the element non-visible, you can add a value between the parenthesis to dictate a duration for a transition. Numerical values are in milliseconds `.hide(1000)`, you can also use `.hide(slow)`, `.hide(fast)`, etc. [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

---

**Starting a countdown**

In order to delay the hiding of your element, you need to split your code up into two different functions. The command `.setTimeout(hideTestje,1000)` starts a countdown before running the `hideTestje` function with a countdown duration of 1000 milliseconds (1 second).

**Cancelling a countdown**

If the user then continues to input into the textbox, and the value meets your two conditions, then the command `.clearTimeout(delayedTestjeHide)` will cancel the countdown.

```js
var delayedTestjeHide;

$('#FenceMeters').on('input', function() {
  if($('#FenceMeters').val() != "" && Number($('#FenceMeters').val()) >=5){
     $('#testje').show();
     $('#SummaryHTML').hide();
     window.clearTimeout(delayedTestjeHide);
  } else{
      delayedTestjeHide = window.setTimeout(hideTestje,1000);
  }
});


function hideTestje() {      
    $('#testje').hide();
    $('#SummaryHTML').show();
}
```

```css
#testje {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="FenceMeters">
<div id="testje">testje</div>
<div id="SummaryHTML">SummaryHTML</div>
```

Comment: I still have a weird animation type thing. See here: https://gyazo.com/f244695502228ede7eba9ee0c3f9b846

Comment: I've updated the code, you need to delay `$("#SummaryHTML").show()` as well, or they are both visible during the countdown. You just move it into the `hideTestje` function